# How to make sure that dynamic DOM elements have correct css using jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile app using jQuery mobile. 
I try to add some inputs dynamically, however, jQuery mobile style is not added to dynamically created input. 
I have created a simple app: http://jsfiddle.net/jGhqS/

I would like to have all my new inputs inherit default jQuery mobile css. 
How do I do it?
And Why is it not working by default?

Code to add input dynamically:

```
$('#pageone').append("<input id='laskaInput' type='email' name='email' placeholder='1@1.com'>");
```

Comment: you are appending elements with same `ID` many times .`ID` must be unique use `class` instead .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [.trigger("create")](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/faq/triggering-create-on-injected-content-does-not-work.php)

```
 $('#pageone').append("<input class='laskaInput' type='email' name='email' placeholder='1@1.com'>")
            .trigger("create");
```

---

you are appending elements with same `ID` many times .`ID` must be unique use `class` instead

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178)

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/byY4h/)</kbd>

---

jQuery mobile adds its own styles and classes at Page load.The element which are added later need to `.trigger("create");` so that jQuery mobile adds styles and classes to new elements added .

---

> Note:- It is important to remember that create must be triggered on
>   the parent container and not on the individual element that needs to
>   be enhanced.

Read [Triggering create on injected HTML does not work.](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/faq/triggering-create-on-injected-content-does-not-work.php)

Comment: @TusharGupta Love you for .trigger("create")  :))

Answer (score 0):

because you haven't included a class

here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').click(function () {
        $('#pageone').append("<input id='lskaInput' type='email'  name='email' placeholder='1@1.com' class='ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset'>");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jGhqS/2/