# aplying jquery mobile-1.4.5 functions on dynimacly created DOM objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

i'm creating dynamic some DOM object's in HTML, such as `<tr>` etc. with js.

```
    <script>
        var addTr = document.createElement("tr");
        var addTd1 = document.createElement("td")
        var tArtikel = document.createElement('input');
        tArtikel.setAttribute("type", "text");
        tArtikel.setAttribute("class", "artikel");
        tArtikel.setAttribute("value", "");
        addTd1.appendChild(tArtikel);
        addTr.appendChild(addTd1);
        document.getElementById("tablecontent").appendChild(addTr);
    </script>
```

After including the library's the new created object's doesnt get the function and properties from the  jquery mobile-1.4.5.js and CSS.

```
!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

I tryied to solve this with $.getScript() but the browser is stuck on loading.

```
var url = "./js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js";
$("#neuerArtikel").click(function () {
$.getScript(url, addTablerow);
});
```

Comment: To build new table`$("table").table().enhanceWithin();`. To rebuild existing table `$("table").table("rebuild").enhanceWithin();` http://api.jquerymobile.com/table/#method-rebuild

Comment: Thank you, for you fast response. i found the help in the relations on right side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170339/how-to-make-sure-that-dynamic-dom-elements-have-correct-css-using-jquery-mobile?rq=1

Comment: The answer is old, don't use `.trigger("create")`.